Git did not show conflict or changes in PR
I'm working in the same project as many other people in my company, but I've come across a git error that I've never seen before
I created my branch before my colleague did and merged it into main AFTER he did. The thing is, in my PR, git did not show conflicts in aaa.csproj neither showed me that we modified the same file. I was expecting that it would show the conflict resolution part before merging, but i received the message that there were no conflicts to be solved.

Basicaly, git brought his changes, brought my changes and did not consider the changes HE made in a file I also modified, it only considered my changes. Why's that? Is it because I only had changes from main from before his PR?

Did your changes conflict with the other changes?   If you made changes in lines 10-20, and the other commit changes lines 55-60, then git will consider them conflict free.  git is just doing textual analysis.  If your changes cause issues, you need to catch that in your test suite.

In the project I was working on, there was a package update from branch X (see in the picture). The thing is, the package version was only updated in the package.config file and not in the .csproj file.
That solves my problem: there were no conflicts in aaa.csproj because there was no changes for that specific package there. It was a miscommunication error.
